# Generic Paramter 'T' could not be inferred - Problems with generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, storekit

I have this class called openApp, thats meant to open another app using a redirect url and store kit. Im not too familiar with generics and its making me run into this error

> Generic Parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Am I not handling the use of `T` correctly? I really don't understand whats going on here.

```
public class openApp {
        static func openOrDownloadPlayPortal<T>(delegate: T) where T: SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate, T:
            UIViewController {

            let storeProductVC = SKStoreProductViewController()
            let playPortalURL = URL(string: "redirect url")!


            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(playPortalURL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(playPortalURL)
            }
            else {
                let vc = SKStoreProductViewController()
                let params = [
                    SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: "app identifier"
                ]
                vc.loadProduct(withParameters: params) { success, err in
                    if let err = err {

                    }
                }
                vc.delegate = delegate
                delegate.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the code it your question the same as the code in your project of have you simplified it? I don't get a "generic parameter T could not be inferred" error when I try it locally.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yes its the same code from the project not simplified. Thats interesting you don't get the same result.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: I just copied-pasted your code snippet and it worked fine. What's the Swift version you are using?

Comment: @AhmadF swift 4. It probably would help more to say its specifically firing the error off here

`@IBAction func open(_ sender: Any) {
      openApp.openOrDownloadPlayPortal(delegate: self)
    }`

Comment: @Sweeper see my last comment

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the class where you put that code in?

Comment: @Sweeper `@objc class Profile : UIViewController {`

Comment: Edit your question to show where the error *actually occurs*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the issue appears when *calling* the `openOrDownloadPlayPortal` method as:

```
openApp.openOrDownloadPlayPortal(delegate: self)
```

You will face the mentioned error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

if your class does *not* conforms to the `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate`. For example, let's assume that you are calling it in `ViewController` class, as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        openApp.openOrDownloadPlayPortal(delegate: self)
    }
}
```

So, you have to make sure that `ViewController` has:

```
extension ViewController: SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {
    // ...
}
```

The reason of the error is: the compiler assumes that the `T` parameter in `openOrDownloadPlayPortal` method has to conforms to the `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate`, therefore implementing

```
openApp.openOrDownloadPlayPortal(delegate: self)
```

means that it will not be recognized as the appropriate type for the `T`, unless you make `self` (`ViewController` in the above example) to be conformable to `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate`.